# Exception handling with Yahoo-finance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to scrape data using yfinance and have met a road block when trying to retrieve a ticker with no data, the error is `- 7086.KL: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted`.

How do I try catch this error? I've tried try catching it as seen in the code below but it still prints that error.

The code:

```
tickerdata = yf.Ticker("7086.KL")

try:
    history = tickerdata.history(start="2019-06-01", end="2020-05-01")
except ValueError as ve:
    print("Error")
```

Any advise on how to solve this?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a try-catch in the function call of yf and that's printing the error?

Comment: Apparently it's not raising a `ValueError`. Please [edit] your question and include the actual tranceback (if you want a good answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had a look at the source code. It looks like they are indeed just printing the message. But they are also adding the error to a dictionary in the shared.py file. You can use this to check for errors:

```py
from yfinance import shared


ticker = <ticker as string>
tickerdata = yf.Ticker(ticker)

history = tickerdata.history(start="2019-06-01", end="2020-05-01")
error_message = shared._ERRORS[ticker]
```

Comment: That's the problem. No error is being thrown. I've looked through the class object code on github and found no indication that it is an error.

Comment: Where does the error popup? In the returned object or stdout?

Comment: It's not from the object, I'm sure of that. I assume stdout.

Comment: I solved the problem by just skipping the empty dataframe returned but this works also. Thank you for getting back to me. How did you know the errors were being appended into the _ERROR dictionary?

Comment: Not a problem, line 162 of https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/blob/master/yfinance/base.py

Comment: @cswannabe How did you do that in the end? I have the same issue.