# Is there a way to have YahooFinancials return a "ticker exists" true false in Python?

Tags: python, stock, yahoo, yfinance, ticker

There are better ways to skin this cat but I am going through it as an exercise to help me understand some of the python structures.

I have a list of stock tickers from various markets.  Some of them or invalid, I don't know why but they are.  I was using the yahoo financial historic download URL as a hack to iterate through them and find which ones returned something and which ones returned an error.  I then kept a list of the good ones.  That didn't work so well as the program stopped returning valid stocks.  I think it was just pinging too fast but no matter.

I jumped over to YahooFinancials API and I can make it all work except I don't see how I can iterate through that same sketchy list and find the good tickers.  It returns a string on a failure as opposed to a File not found exception so I can't trap it in a try/catch block.

Is there a way to test for this or is there some method in the API that would allow me to test for ticker validity?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
from yahoofinancials import YahooFinancials

df = pd.DataFrame()
dfG = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name'])
dfB = pd.DataFrame(columns=['name'])

GoodList = []
BadList = []

file = open("NYSE.txt", 'r')
symbols = file.readlines()
file.close

for i in symbols:
    try:
        dff = yf.download(i.strip(), 
                      start='2021-06-09', 
                      end='2021-06-12', 
                      progress=False,
        )
    except:
        BadList.append(i.strip())
        print(f'The file {i.strip()} does not exist')
    else:
        GoodList.append(i.strip())
        print(i.strip())

dfG["name"] = GoodList
dfB["name"] = BadList
dfG.to_csv('NYSE_Good.txt')
dfB.to_csv('NYSE_Bad.txt')
```

And example bad output is as such

1 Failed download:

- PEB-H: No data found, symbol may be delisted

Which isn't an exception but I am not sure how to capture this and treat keep it out of the mix.  Understand that the wording is left over from when i was checking for a historical file on Yahoo so that is why it looks a little odd.  Just prototyping here.

Any thoughts?

Edit:  I couldn't get the exception handling to work properly so I punted and used the condition of the returned empty dataset to handle it.  It solved the problem.

```
for i in symbols:
    try:
        df2 = yf.download(i.strip(), 
                      start='2021-06-09', 
                      end='2021-06-12', 
                      progress=False,
        )
        
    except:
        print(f'There was an exception for {i.strip()} ')
    else:
        if df2.empty:
            BadList.append(i.strip())
            print(f'The file {i.strip()} does not exist')
        else:
            GoodList.append(i.strip())
            print(i.strip())
```

Comment: The function has the ability to hold error messages, so you can use it for error handling. Please refer to [Exception handling with Yahoo-finance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61690798/exception-handling-with-yahoo-finance).

Comment: as a rule of thumb, this resource is helpful if you are deep into yahoo finance works https://investexcel.net/all-yahoo-finance-stock-tickers/